# New TML files don't compile automatically in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tapestry

I am working my way through the Tapestry 5 tutorial and I have notices that changes to the TML files (or new TML files for that matter) don't automatically compile from inside eclipse.  I can only get the new TML files or changes to any TML file to be realized by going out to the command line and "mvn package".  That can't be right.

In eclipse this is a Maven project and I executed the whole "mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true" thing, so its hard to believe that the eclipse project is not configured correctly.

It is as if *tml files do not qualify for automatic copy into the targets directory like compiled *java files would or *properties file.

What do I have to do to get this project configured for more interactive debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I always add a test dependency to Jetty and launch it with the following class. Because the code is run from eclipse's classpath, whatever eclipse sees, the jetty web app also sees. Therefore you never have any problems with resource dirs.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
package jetty;
import org.apache.tapestry5.SymbolConstants;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Connector;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection;
import org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

/**
 * For jetty 6
 * @see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty#comment-4391085
 */
public class JettyWebServer {
    public static String     context = "/";
    public static int         port     = 8069;

    private Server jettyServer;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty(SymbolConstants.PRODUCTION_MODE, "false");

        jettyServer = new Server();
        Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(port);
        connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        jettyServer.addConnector(connector);

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("src/web/", JettyWebServer.context);
        context.setLogUrlOnStart(true);
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        jettyServer.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
        contexts.addHandler(context);
        jettyServer.setHandler(contexts);

        jettyServer.start();
    }

    public void join() throws Exception {
        jettyServer.join();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        if (jettyServer != null)
            jettyServer.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JettyWebServer server = new JettyWebServer();
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this isn't a Tapestry issue, it is a Maven/Jetty-Plugin issue. Maven copies your files around, a changing them in Eclipse changes them in place, and Maven doesn't copy them into the location where the running Tapestry application can see the changes.  I use RunJettyRun Eclipse plugin to run my Tapestry applications inside Eclipse (before I switched to IDEA).

Comment: I've pretty much reached the same conclusion.  The Maven plug-in is getting in the way.  Its days like this that I consider chucking the whole IDE thing and moving back into emacs.  Thanks to all for the looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your template files next to the class files in `src/main/java`? You need to make sure Maven treats files from that location as resources in addition to the usual `/resources` location. This configuration should work:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This also makes the Maven Eclipse plugin (and M2 integration) behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.  My *tml files are currently located in src/main/resources (the Maven default, no?).  I tried putting the <resources> tag you suggested under the pom.xml's <build> tag (without the specification for /src/main/java, because I don't have any resources there) and nothing changed.  That is to say "mvn package" from the command line always works, but just letting eclipse do its autocompile thing and hoping the RunJettyRun Jetty instance will get the updates never sees the updates to the *tml files (or the *.properties files as well).

Comment: Okay, with the TMLs in /resources, you should not have a problem. I have never used RunJettyRun, though, I always execute the `jetty:run` target from Eclipse.